# Create an offline version of layers in ESRI WebGIS?

Tags: layers, arcgis-online, offline, web-gis

I am new with Online/WebGIS concept from ESRI and mostly worked on ArcMap 10.3 until now. We have recently created a WebGIS for one of our clients with a lot of vector layers which is pretty big data.

The client has recently asked for an offline version of the whole data in WebGIS including all the layers and their Attributes in Windows System and just as read-only usage.

The Client does not have ArcGIS in house and they just saw our delivery in our office. I search a bit in this regard and found "ArcGIS Explorer" related but I am not if that is the best approach.

As the client has no ArcGIS software, which approach in your opinion would be helpful to do this task?

Comment: Which type of device would your client be using (Windows, iOS, Android)? Will he need to edit data, or is everything read-only?

Comment: Windows and as read only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which brand of WebGIS are you using now, Esri?

In that case,  the most obvious way would be to use one of the Esri apps, such as [Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.esri.explorer) or [Collector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.esri.arcgis.collector), which both have offline capabilities (also available in the Microsoft Store and the Apple App Store).

These apps are 'freely' available, but are obviously only useful if you already have ArcGIS Server, or using ArcGIS Online.

There are some requirements as to how the data should be published to be available offline, but that is outside the scope of this question.

**UPDATE**

Since you indicated that your client is using Windows, and the data is read-only, one option would be to install [ArcGIS Earth](https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/arcgis-earth) on the client's machines. You would have to export all your feature data to shapefiles, and basemaps (if you are using those) to tile packages. See [Supported data types](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-earth/use/data-support.htm).

ArcGIS Explorer is also free, and still [available for download](https://community.esri.com/community/gis/applications/arcgis-explorer-desktop/blog/2017/12/12/arcgis-explorer-desktop-retired-1012017). However it is retired for almost a year now, so I wouldn't recommend using it.

Another free option is [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/). I haven't really used it myself, but there are many on this site who have. It is a lot more advanced than ArcGIS Earth.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. Is there any Limitation for Explorer or Collector? As I mentioned, the created layers are really big data.

Comment: I suppose there are. But in my experience the first limit we hit is storage space on the device itself, especially for offline basemaps.

Comment: So how does your client access your webgis now?

Comment: We have just presented them in our Office and informed them About the Costs so now they have asked for the Version of the data but as offline

Comment: That changes thing a bit. It would have been useful to have that information in your original question

Comment: Did they ask for 'a version of the data', or 'an offline version of the entire webgis'?

Comment: Thank you for the update. I am going to inform myself more About the ArcEarth . But does is cover all the data and even the Attributes?

Comment: 'All data' is a bit broad. Please specify. Or start by reading the docs ;-)

Comment: I read About the GIS earth and even install it and made some example. but the Problem is that as an Export you can just create Image or static map not a dynamic map for the Client. Is it correct ?

Comment: It sounds like you showed the client the subscription costs and they didn't want to pay.  If they want to interact with the data for free, they should get QGIS.  It has basically the same functionality as ArcMap for viewing and querying data.  If your office is paying for the data storage in ArcGIS online, you can create level 1 accounts for them to view the data online.  If you're paying for storage, you should have some level 1 accounts available.